# Incorporate SSH functionality into Android App

Tags: android, android-fragments, ssh

I would like to allow the user to use an SSH terminal in a fragment within my app. Is there a "best" way to do this?

Comment: Use the jsch library.

Comment: A best way to do... what? Have a fragment? Write a terminal emulator? Communicate via SSH? Something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare The goal is all three - terminal emulator in a fragment capable of ssh communication

Comment: That is well beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: The question is whether there is a library that adds an ssh interface to you app by extending an activity or some other method. I think you may have overcomplicated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: After much research we decided to go with the jsch library and just make our own custom interface to replicate terminal functionality.